# azure cli command is not working when setting minTlsVersion to 1.2 for FunctionApp's

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli

when i run the below command in Azure CLI it appears to work, because i get a big dump of JSON back that shows all of my settings for the function app, with it's "minTlsVersion" set to 1.2.

```
az functionapp config set --min-tls-version 1.2 --id"/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Production/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/func-app-name"
```

However, when i then run:

```
az functionapp list
```

and check the functionapp whose config i just updated, it is back to "minTlsVersion": null.

I tried with multiple function apps, but no luck.

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Github issue1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16698) and [Github issue2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21548). This behaviour in **`az functionapp list`** and **`az webapp list`** is by default ***where the site-config values are shown as null to avoid performance issues on the list commands.***

As a workaround you can use **`az function app show`** command to get the accurate value like below:-

```bash
az functionapp show --name siliconfunctls1 --resource-group siliconrg89
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Received **minTlsVersion value** successfully like below:-

[image]

***When I tried to set the `min-tls-version to 1.2` and then tried to list the site config setting, I received null response, Refer below:-***

**Commands:-**

```bash
az functionapp config set --name siliconfunctls1 --resource-group siliconrg89 --min-tls-version 1.2

az functionapp list
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**`az functionapp list`** **output showed `minTlsVersion as null`**

[image]

**Azure CLI command reference:-**
[az functionapp | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest)